# Split large collection into smaller ones?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a collection that is potentially going to be very large. Now I know MongoDB doesn't really have a problem with this, but I don't really know how to go about designing a schema that  can handle a very large dataset comfortably. So I'm going to give an outline of the problem.

We are collecting large amounts of data for our customers. Basically, when we gather this data it is represented as a 3-tuple, lets say (a, b, c), where b and c are members of sets B and C respectively. In this particular case we know that the B and C sets will not grow very much over time. For our current customers we are talking about ~200,000 members. However, the A set is the one that keeps growing over time. Currently we are at about ~2,000,000 members per customer, but this is going to grow (possibly rapidly.) Also, there are 1->n relations between b->a and c->a.

The workload on this data set is basically split up into 3 use cases. The collections will be periodically updated, where A will get the most writes, and B and C will get some, but not many. The second use case is random access into B, then aggregating over some number of documents in C that pertain to b \in B. And the last usecase is basically streaming a large subset from A and B to generate some new data.

The problem that we are facing is that the indexes are getting quite big. Currently we have a test setup with about 8 small customers, the total dataset is about 15GB in size at the moment, and indexes are running at about 3GB to 4GB. The problem here is that we don't really have any hot zones in our dataset. It's basically going to get an evenly distributed load amongst all documents.

Basically we've come up with 2 options to do this. The one that I described above, where all data for all customers is piled into one collection. This means we'd have to create an index om some field that links the documents in that collection to a particular customer.

The other options is to throw all b's and c's together (these sets are relatively small) but divide up the C collection, one per customer. I can imangine this last solution being a bit harder to manage, but since we rarely access data for multiple customers at the same time, it would prevent memory problems. MongoDB would be able to load the customers index into memory and just run from there.

What are your thoughts on this?

P.S.: I hope this wasn't too vague, if anything is unclear I'll go into some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the larger set (A if I followed along correctly), could reasonably be put into its own database.  I say database rather than collection, because now that 2.2 is released you would want to minimize lock contention between the busier database and the others, and to do that a separate database would be best (2.2 introduced database level locking).  That is looking at this from a single replica set model, of course.

Also the index sizes sound a bit out of proportion to your data size - are you sure they are all necessary?  Pruning unneeded indexes, combining and using compound indexes may well significantly reduce the pain you are hitting in terms of index growth (it would potentially make updates and inserts more efficient too).  This really does need specifics and probably belongs in another question, or possibly a thread in the mongodb-user group so multiple eyes can take a look and make suggestions.

If we look at it with the possibility of sharding thrown in, then the truly important piece is to pick a shard key that allows you to make sure locality is preserved on the shards for the pieces you will frequently need to access together.  That would lend itself more toward a single sharded collection (preserving locality across multiple related sharded collections is going to be very tricky unless you manually split and balance the chunks in some way).  Sharding gives you the ability to scale out horizontally as your indexes hit the single instance limit etc. but it is going to make the shard key decision very important.

Again, specifics for picking that shard key are beyond the scope of this more general discussion, similar to the potential index review I mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I just installed 2.2 and am going to look into putting A into it's own database.